# Apache POI: Word get picture dimensions

Tags: java, apache-poi, doc

I am trying to determine the actual size of embedded images in MS Word documents using

```
        HWPFDocument docB = new HWPFDocument(fileInputStream);
        PicturesTable picB = docB.getPicturesTable();
        List picturesB = picB.getAllPictures();
        for (Object o : picturesB) {
            Picture pic = (Picture) o;
            int height = pic.getHeight();
            int width = pic.getWidht();
        }
```

This works fine for some images but for others getHeight() and getWidth() will only return -1 as stated in the [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/Picture.html#getHeight%28%29).
So is there any other way to get the actual size of these pictures in the document?

Comment: What about copying them and saving them to disk to manipulate them via another method?  I'd be worried that they're vector graphics without determinable sizes.

Comment: well if I save them as images I wont't be able to tell the size it was in Word anymore. Even vector graphics would have some size in a Word document.

Comment: I wonder if you need to associate the document with some form of renderer or print-preview before the layout size is known. (sorry I can't be more helpful)

Comment: Did you try iterating over sections, paragraphs, and character runs?  The documentation suggests this is a better way to get a true list of pictures. (Not sure if it'll fix the size problem)

Comment: No I haven't yet but I can try. However I don't expect this to make much difference.

Comment: //Update: Just tried, same result :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` you may resort to [`getDxaGoal()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/Picture.html#getDxaGoal%28%29), resp. [`getDyaGoal()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/Picture.html#getDyaGoal%28%29). These represent the original size of the image prior to scaling / cropping in [twips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip).

You can then multiply this with `getVerticalScalingFactor() / 1000.0` resp. `getHorizontalScalingFactor() / 1000.0` to get the final (rendered) size. Division by 1000.0 is necessary because those scaling factors are given per mille.